# QML OpenGL game redraw loop

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qml

I am making a 3D game with OpenGL ES 2.0 and want to use QML as an overlay for the user interfaces.

I know that I can embed my OpenGL code inside a QGLWidget but how can I force QML to redraw the view as often as possible?

Additionally will I get performance issues because I am embedding the OpenGL view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render your game with OpenGL and use QML for the UI, consider using the Qt Quick Scene Graph:

- [Mixing Scene Graph and OpenGL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#mixing-scene-graph-and-opengl)
- [Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html)